# MySQL - Selecting most ordered products from list of a number of categories

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create an efficient SQL query, but running into problems.

Consider a MySQL table with the following 3 fields.

PRODUCTS TABLE:

```
Product ID | Category ID | Orders in the Last 30 Days
```

There are other fields, but of no significance for this question.
There are 140,000 products in this table.

I then have another table which creates a "nested" category structure. This may or not be important for the question.

CATEGORY TABLE:

```
Category ID | Root ID | Category Name
```

This creates a tree of categories, with "0" indicating a root category. 
There are approx 2,500 categories in this table.

Problem: Give me the most popular 20 products in a given category. Simple enough if there are no nested categories, but in my case I have a very "nested" category structure - and I want to provide the popular products from all categories "below" the one requested.

I have a perl script which can very quickly go and retrieve all of the categories that sit BENEATH the requested category.
It then forms an SQL query which looks like the following:

SELECT `productid` FROM `products` WHERE `catid`='1' or `catid`='2' or `catid`='3'..... etc etc ORDER BY `ordersinlast30d` DESC LIMIT 0,20

This works fine if my "OR" list is only a few long, but bear in mind if I ask this for one of my "root" categories, or just ask for category "0" (i.e. every category underneath) this is creating an "OR" list which is 2,500 long. This is taking in the region of 20 seconds to execute.
Really 50-100ms is the max I can really wait.

To me, it seems the easiest way for the database to execute this would be to simply sort the whole table by `ordersinlast30d` then go through line by line matching if the category ID is requested. Then stop at 20. This is why I'm fairly sure there must be an efficient way of constructing this query. I'm guessing the database is executing all of my "WHERE" statements first which is what is taking the time.

Any ideas how I can make an efficient SQL query for this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by using an SQL query optimiser.

For future reference, in case any stumbles across this, use IN not "OR"

So

```
SELECT `productid` FROM `products` WHERE `catid` IN (123,456,789) ORDER BY `orders30d` DESC LIMIT 0,20
```